# Get Last Record for each day in a Group

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to get Last/Latest record for each day. For 14th Dec there are two records I want to get 5 PM record as it is the last record for that day but if you see the `row_number(rn = 2 & 3)`, so it does not pick this record and only give me pointintime record that is of today (15th Dec as its rn = 1).

```
ITCFID  ControlId   ResourceId  DateTime    rn
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/14/2021 5:00 PM  2
P05.01.03   CloudFront.1    AWS:::Acount:1111111111111  12/14/2021 06:01 AM 3
```

This is the query I am using:

```
WITH
  Pointintimesecurityfindings AS (
    SELECT
      *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResourceId,ControlId,itcfid ORDER BY DateTime DESC) rn
    FROM itcf_final_summary_dashboard
)    
SELECT *
FROM Pointintimesecurityfindings
WHERE rn = 1
```

For a particular ITCFID -> There can be multiple Control ID and Control ID can have multiple Resource ID. I want to get for a particular itcfid -> Unique Control ID -> Unique ResourceID -> Get latest record for that day.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Noted. Let me update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the latest per day, you need to partition by day e.g.

SQL Server solution as originally tagged:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
  ResourceId
  , ControlId
  , itcfid
  , DATEPART(year,[DateTime])
  , DATEPART(dayofyear,[DateTime]
) ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) rn
```

Presto solution for updated question:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
    , ResourceId
    , ControlId
    , itcfid
    , DATE_FORMAT(Datetime,'%Y') 
    , DATE_FORMAT(Datetime,'%j')
    ORDER BY DateTime DESC
) rn
```

Comment: I am using Athena, it says Function DATEPART not registered.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Most of the sql functions work in athena but it does not.

Comment: minor tweaks used date_parse instead of DATEPART, DATE_TRUNC does not work. But thank you very much for the help.

Comment: sure go ahead, it might help somebody

Comment: , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  ResourceId , ControlId , itcfid , date_format(Datetime,'%Y'), date_format(Datetime,'%j')
     ORDER BY DateTime DESC) rn